# Error in flashing my jetson nano with sdkmanager as well as command line using a MAC OS

Tags: command-line-interface, android-sdk-manager, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am trying to flash my jetson nano after I forgot the password to the account. I am referring to this website[text](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/reComputer_J2021_J202_Flash_Jetpack/#flashing-jetpack-os-via-nvidia-sdk-manager)

I am using a Mac OS and when I try to follow the sdkmanager method, I am getting this error and I dont know how to get past it;

```
zsh: command not found: sdkmanager
```

I then tried the command line method. After I got to the point where I unzip all the necessary packages, I run the script

```
sudo ./apply_binaries.sh
```

But it is giving me this error

```
Use: apply_binaries.sh [--bsp|-b PATH] [--root|-r PATH] [--target-overlay] [--help|-h]
    This script installs tegra binaries
    Options are:
    --bsp|-b PATH
                   bsp location (bsp, readme, installer)
    --root|-r PATH
                   install toolchain to PATH
    --target-overlay|-t
                   untar NVIDIA target overlay (.tbz2) instead of
                   pre-installing them as Debian packages
    --help|-h
                   show this help
```

I used the method of setting the environmental variable for this but it still showed this message.

For the SDKmanager method, I tried setting up the path to where my .deb file is stored but it showed the same error.
For the command line method, I tried setting the environmental variable LDK_ROOTFS_DIR but it still showed this message.